# Proof that the sequence $\left\{u_{n}\right\}$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the sequence $(u_{n}) := \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n+3}}$, I want show that $(u_{n})$ converges to $0$ using the $\epsilon$ definition of convergence. My attempt is as follows.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow \left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n+3}} - 0\right| = \left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n+3}}\right| < \epsilon$.

Now the problem is that I am trying to get an expression in the absolute value term that I can use to determine my $N$.

In one of my attempts, I claimed that $\sqrt[3]{n+3} > \sqrt[3]{n}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ implies that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n+3}} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$. Then, I would say that $\left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n+3}}\right| < \left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\right| < \epsilon$.

My question is, is the above inequality true, and can I use that to find an expression for $N$?

Thanks.

Comment: You just need $n>\epsilon^{-3}$.

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: @geetha290krm Alright, seems like my workings should be correct?

Comment: @LiKwokKeung, alright. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: That means $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}} < \epsilon \Rightarrow n > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon^{3}}$, which means that we could set $N = \dfrac{1}{\epsilon^{3}}$?

Comment: Usually, $N$ is taken to be a positive integer. So you have take $N$ to be an integer exceeding $\frac 1 {\epsilon^{3}}$.

Comment: So, $N > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon^{3}}$?

Comment: Just remember with problems like these you can "overdo it" without a problem. For example. $N>\epsilon^{-3}-3$ is enough, but you don't need to notice that. When in doubt, choose $N$ so large there's no difficulty in proving it'll do.

Comment: @J.G. Okay, got it. Thanks.

Comment: @HelloWorld To be formal, $N$ has to be an integer. You may take $$N=\lfloor \frac{1}{\varepsilon^3} \rfloor+1$$.

Comment: @LikwokKeung Cool, thanks.